How can you edit the Separate and Combine Colour Nodes to include LCH Colour Space?
I have already asked this before here on this site and Reddit, but I’m determined to find a solution to my problem. So here’s the basic gist:
I am beginning work on a project that involves colourising a clip from an old black and white Doctor Who episode. I want to make it look as realistic as possible. Unfortunately, however, the best way I can go about it usually is utilising an LCH (lLuminance, Chroma, Hue) colour space which can guarantee the best possible results. I have tried using the main colour spaces within the Separate and Combine Colour nodes like HSV and YUV, but they can be a challenge to deal with when trying to get good skin tones (which is a high priority for me). With that said, since Blender is a customisable software, is it possible to re-edit the code of the Separate and Combine Colour nodes to include the LCH Colour Space? Can you create a similar node to them using Blender's Python Scripting interface to include I want? Whatever the answer is, can any of you please show me how to do it?
